# My program crashes at fseek

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am able to open a file using android_fopen. The program crashes when I try to find the size of the file. Here's the code snippet.

```
    FILE* fp = android_fopen("www/backspace.png","rb");
    if(fp = NULL){
        LOGI("CANNOT OPEN BACKSPACE FILE");
        return;
    }


    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    long fsize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

The program crashes at the first fseek statement. I am unable to find a cause. fseek should work find for png files.

Comment: `if(fp = NULL){`  --> `if(fp == NULL){`

Comment: Increase your compiler's warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Also, unless you have a particular reason, there's no reason to compare to NULL - just write `if (!fp)` instead. It's just as expressive, can't be an accidental assignment, keeps working when you use smart pointers, etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a very disappointing mistake from my side. I should not have done this comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fp = NULL` is an assignment.

Use `fp == NULL` instead.

Comment: Or better yet, use `std::fstream`.